# Anagram Finder Python

Tags: python, anagram

I want to return a list of the words in 'listofwords.txt' that are anagrams of some string 'b'

```
def find_anagrams(a,b): ##a is the listofwords.txt
    f=open('listofwords.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        word=line.strip()
        wordsorted= ''.join(sorted(line))
        for word in f:

            if wordsorted == ''.join(sorted(word)):
                    print word
```

Why is it just giving me anagrams of the first word in the list?

Also how can I return a message if no anagrams are found?

Comment: Where do you even use `a` or `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `for` is incorrect. And you are comparing wordsorted with ''.join(sorted(word)), which are the same thing. This should work better:

```
def find_anagrams(a, b):
    f = open(a, 'r')
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip()
        wordsorted = ''.join(sorted(word))
        if wordsorted == ''.join(sorted(b)):
            print word
```

Now, make sure you close the file (or, better, use `with` statement).

**Edit:** about returning a message, the best thing to do is actually to return a list of the anagrams found. Then you decide what to do with the words (either print them, or print a message when the list is empty, or whatever you want). So it could be like

```
def find_anagrams(a, b):
    anagrams = []
    with open(a, 'r') as infile:
        for line in f:
            word = line.strip()
            wordsorted = ''.join(sorted(word))
            if wordsorted == ''.join(sorted(b)):
                anagrams.append(word)
    return anagrams
```

Then you can use it as

```
anagrams = find_anagrams('words.txt', 'axolotl')
if len(anagrams) > 0:
    for anagram in anagrams:
       print anagram
else:
    print "no anagrams found"
```

Comment: do you know what `b` is?

Comment: it's the word to find anagrams for.

Comment: How can I return a message if no anagrams are found?

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the file iterator `f` in the inner loop. Once the inner loop is finished, `f` will be exhausted and you exit the outer loop immediately, so you don't actually get past the first line.

If you want to have two independent loops over all the lines in your file, one solution (I'm sure this problem could be solved more efficiently) would be to first read the lines into a list and then iterating over the list:

```
with open('listofwords.txt') as f: # note: 'r' is the default mode
    lines = f.readlines() # also: using `with` is good practice
for line in lines:
    word = line.strip()
    wordsorted = ''.join(sorted(line))
    for word in lines:
        if word == ''.join(sorted(word)):
            print word
```

Edit: My code doesn't solve the problem you stated (I misunderstood it first, see matiasg's answer for the correct code), but my answer still explains why you only get the anagrams for the first word in the file.